# Is it possible to use a formula within a formula in Data studio?

Tags: looker-studio

Is it possible to use a formula within a formula in Data studio?

I would like to do something like :

```
myField=metric1 + metric2

CASE WHEN MyField > 4 THEN ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create two separate fields in the data source that hosts the metrics you want to formulate. Create the field MyField first and then create your second field referencing the other. It is a dependency of the formula.

Field Name: MyField

```
metric1 + metric2
```

Field Name: MyField2

```
MyField > 4
```

The CASE WHEN function works well when you are wanting to build them out as a dimension to use in say a Scorecard. The above fields would be metrics.

Answer (score 0):

### 0) Summary

Use **EITHER** #1 or #2

### 1) [`CASE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724)

It can now be achieved in a single [`CASE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724) statement (the [11 Mar 2021 Update](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10331528#mar-11-2021) included enhancements to **Conditional Expressions** in [`CASE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724) statements); thus where `metric1` and `metric2`represent the two metrics and the requirement is to create a **Boolean** field where >4 is `TRUE` `ELSE FALSE`, the below does the trick:

```
CASE
  WHEN metric1 + metric2 > 4 THEN TRUE
  ELSE FALSE
END
```

### 2) [`IF`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10468770)

The [11 Mar 2021 Update](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10331528#mar-11-2021) also introduced a new **Conditional Expression**, [`IF`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10468770), thus adding an alternative approach to the [`CASE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724) statement above:

```
IF((metric1 + metric2 > 4), TRUE, FALSE)
```

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/b42b5dd6-745e-4545-af58-ea49922a9392) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]